# TailwindCSS content files within conf

Tags: javascript, configuration, tailwind-css, redwoodjs

Problem: My tailwindcss config file does not recognise & interpret the CSS written within the components. It works fine for tailwindcss written in CSS files.

I am using [Redwood.js](https://redwoodjs.com/).

In RedwoodJs, the tailwindCSS config file is stored at `./web/src/config/`.

'./web/src/config/tailwind.config.js':

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./web/src/components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./web/src/pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./web/src/layouts/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./web/src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
```

As per [tailwindcss docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#configuring-source-paths):

> "Paths are relative to your project root, not your tailwind.config.js
> file, so if your tailwind.config.js file is in a custom location, you
> should still write your paths relative to the root of your project."*

Which is what I have done above. However, the classNames used within components are not transformed into CSS in the browser. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

---

**SOLUTION EDIT:**
Correct string to pass to content is:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./src/layouts/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
```

I fail to understand why the `web` folder is taken as root folder, when it is one-level within the repo. The only justification I can think of is that webpack is somewhere setting the core dir for postcss?

I would love some insight/ feedback into how the working solution is working, when it seems to go against the docs at TailwindCSS...

Comment: have you added tailwind directives to your CSS files, i.e. step 3 here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation?

Comment: Yes I did. Added to index.css file. Screen added above to question.

Comment: @Lukas bizzarely, your deleted solution is almost right. I have no idea why, however, `./src/components/**/*.{js, jsx, ts, tsx}` works. Its working now!

Comment: apparently `/web` is the root path of your project.